# Resolving Coldfusion J2EE sessions with ajax calls to cfc methods using verifyclient

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, remote-access

I am currently utilizing CF session management and have been investigating transitioning to utilizing J2EE session management. In my attempts to do so, ajax requests made ( when CFsession management is set to use J2EE sessions ) to CF cfc remote methods fail the verifyclient authorization. The code below works when session management uses CF session management.

My assumption is that the _cf_clientid is no longer the correct value to pass to the remote method - as it is generated using cfid and cftoken.

How do I successfully implement J2EE session management and utilize remote cfc methods with verifyclient? Or can it not be done? Using CF tag cfajaxproxy is not an option.

The example code below demonstrates how to use jQuery ajax to call a remote cfc method with verifyclient='true', even though CF documentation indicates that the use of cfajaxproxy is required. This is not the case. (Thanks to Ray Camden and DWMommy. ) This leads me to believe that there may also be a work-around to implement a similar method for verifying a client when using J2EE sessions.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="/plugins/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
<cfajaximport />
<script>
$(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.cfc',    
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    method: 'sayHello',
                    yourname: 'Foo'
                    ,_cf_clientid: _cf_clientid
                },
                success: displaySearchResults
            });
});
</script>
<script>
    function displaySearchResults(res){
        $('#searchResults').html( res );
    }
</script>
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

test.cfc

```
component{
    remote any function sayHello ( string yourname = 'anonymous') 
        returnformat='JSON' verifyclient='true'{
        return 'Hello ' & arguments.yourname;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is stored in `_cf_clientid`?  Can you show us an example?  I'm assuming the `cfid` `cftoken` combination. When using J2EE sessions with ColdFusion the session identifier becomes `jsessionid`.  You might need to change your code to use that instead.

Comment: You are correct, the _cf_clientid is generated with the combination of cfid and cftoken. This is why this value has no meaning when using J2EE session management. It is generated regardless with the Application.cfc setting, this.sessionmanagement is set to true. To see an example, create a cf page with the <cfajaximport> tag and view the source. The jsessionid is not available to javascript via cfajaximport and 'hard-coding' the value of session.jsessionid does not appear to work.

Comment: Have you configured ColdFusion to use J2EE sessions?  In the administrator.

Comment: One more point of clarity please, is it failing with `cfajaxproxy` and/or `jQuery` ajax calls?  I may not be able to help you here but this may help others when they see your question.

Comment: I am not using cfajaxproxy. I am calling just as listed above. The request is denied because the verifyclient condition set on the remote method call declines the request because CF does not believe the call is being made from a logged in session. If I remove verifyclient='true' on the method, the call can complete.

Comment: *_cf_clientid is generated with the combination of cfid and cftoken* No, it [also includes `jsessionid`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fd5.html) when J2EE session management is enabled.

Comment: @Leigh - that's why I was wondering if he had enabled the setting in the admin.  He has, so not really sure why this is not working.  I don't have a lot of experience with `verifyClient` so not sure how it really works behind the scenes.  My searches are coming up empty. I did find [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=rI0OZhmcuc0C&pg=PT326&lpg=PT326&dq=j2ee+session+verifyclient&source=bl&ots=ilRlUoAA_p&sig=8bBPuVFFUTtBzTrA4kJKq2lMTgc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=isoSUeScN4ro2gXbwoDADA&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ) which mentions using J2EE sessions and verifyClient that implies it should work.

Comment: @Leigh - I made the assumption that _cf_clientid was encypted URLToken but can not confirm this, even at the resource link.

Comment: @David - See the "Standard client variables" section in the link above. You can verify it is included by dumping `session.urltoken` and comparing its md5 hash ie `#hash(session.urltoken)#` to `_cf_clientid`. The same url works fine when invoked manually, so I am not sure why the jquery call is failing ...

Comment: @Miguel-F - Basically `verifyClient` just pulls the hashed token out of the `url` (or `form`) scope. Then compares the value to that of the current request to ensure they are the same.

Comment: From the docs on verifyClient: "Enable client verification only for code that responds to ColdFusion Ajax client code, because only the ColdFusion Ajax library contains the client-side support code. Enabling client verification for clients other than ColdFusion Ajax applications can result in the client application not running." - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_21.html

Comment: @barnyr "because only the ColdFusion Ajax library contains the client-side support code." - The example code above shows that this is not necessarly true - at least for CF session management.

Comment: @David Indeed, it's got to be possible to replicate, I just thought I'd mention that the docs do point out that this scenario has been considered by the CF developers and documented.

Comment: @David - What version of CF? It works fine for me w/CF10.

Comment: @barnyr - Hm.. I am not sure what developers intended but I interpreted it a little differently. ie That the feature may not work with non-CF applications because those clients might not send the necessary `_cf_clientid` value. However, I see no reason it should not work in a CF page, with or without `cfajaximport`. Since it is just a `hash` of the concatenated session tokens.